# Replace \r\n Values in the MySQL database field by MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I having trouble writing a query on a MySQL table where i have lots of incorrect damaged data.

Example:

```
\r\n\r\nFather-Retired Senior Superintendant of Police\r\n\r\nMother-Retired International School teacher\r\nBrother-Working, married\r\n
```

My Question is how do i remove these "\r\n" via mysql query however i want to preserve them as line breaks in the db.

Like below

```
Father-Retired Senior Superintendant of Police
Mother-Retired International School teacher
Brother-Working, married
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: with the replace() fcn?

Comment: example please, how to preserve the line breaks too ?

Comment: Replace could be used on bringing into front-end without modifying the actual table data. [replace fcn](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: What do you mean "remove" _and_ "preserve"???

Comment: remove strings as "\r\n" but preserver it as line break in the db

Comment: I don't think you want to 'remove'  (or 'replace'). But I suspect that the topic of interpreting line breaks between MySQL and PHP is widely discussed